# "Column is too long" error with BULK INSERT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, bulkinsert

I am trying to run the following command to bulk insert data from a CSV file--

```
 BULK INSERT TestDB.dbo.patent
 FROM 'C:\1patents.csv'
 WITH (FIRSTROW = 1,  FIELDTERMINATOR = '^', ROWTERMINATOR='\n');
```

The error I am getting is this--

> *Msg 4866, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
>   The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 6.
>
>   Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly.
>
>   Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
>   The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>
>   Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>
>   Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".*

Now this is the data in the first row--

```
 00000001^^18360713^295^4^0
```

And in the table the last field (corresp. to the 6th column of data above = 0) is of type 'int'.

What am I doing wrong here? Why am I getting the above error?

Comment: Usually issues are with the row delimiters. Check your delimiters properly.

Answer (score 73):

I got extraction from Oracle/Unix. I replaced `\r\n` by `ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'` and it worked for me.
Thanks a lot !

Comment: This worked for me in a case where the flat file had text qualifier " and field terminator ;.

Comment: is this going to work in every case? or are there any exceptions

Answer (score 35):

Like answered above, I had the same problem importing a csv file into SQL Server. I was using `ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'` and I also tried to use `'\r\n'` and `'\r'`. None of them worked.

But when using `ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'` the table loaded without problems.

I don't know the "why?" behind this, hopefully somebody else can shed light over it.

Comment: 0x0a is hex for LF. Unix uses LF (only) for line breaks, not the Windows standard of CR/LF.

Answer (score 4):

Unless the file source is Unix, chances are the file's row terminator is really

> \r\n

Either use a hex editor to validate the file's terminator, or just try that as the row terminator.

Comment: I tried using the terminator suggested by you- but still getting the same error? Pls let me know if you have any further ideas to help resolve this... thanks....

Comment: An answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4207050/706578 suggests using ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a' if '\n'or '\r\n' isn't working for you.  It worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

I faced the similar problem and came to know that unless the file is UNIX type **\r\n** is fine .

When you generate the format file (**.fmt or .xml**), notice the 3rd column from left. its called **min length** of column. At times sql server defaults it to **2** though you don't mention it in create script. Change that value to **0** . Sometimes you might have to allow NULL also ,so change that to zero and it should work now