# Insert data from CSV to SQL server, insert problem

Tags: sql-server, csv

I have one problem with bulk insert. I have about 7 million records in the csv file, when I make the following query, just half of the total records are entered in the table.
The Query I use:

```
BULK INSERT *Table_Name* FROM 'file path'
    WITH
        (
        FIRSTROW = 1, -- csv dont have header
        FIELDTERMINATOR = '0x0a',
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
        ERRORFILE = '*error file path*',
        TABLOCK
        )
```

Table Creation query:

```
CREATE TABLE *Table_Name*
(
    ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    *Column_Name* varchar(50)
);
```

Where I make a mistake?
How to load all records from a csv file (all 7 million)?

Comment: why `FIELDTERMINATOR = '0x0a'` ? This is `LINE FEED` character

Comment: As Squirrel said, if it's a CSV file why isn't `FIELDTERMINATOR = ','` or something?

Comment: Becouse with ',' I got error - The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 1.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365381/column-is-too-long-error-with-bulk-insert

Comment: You can add BATCHSIZE parameter two your BULK INSERT script so that you decrease inserted row number one time.

Comment: @esat the problem is the same, I try different BATCHSIZE values