# Getting error while bulk insertion

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, t-sql, bulkinsert

I  am getting error when I am trying to do bulk insert:

```
BULK INSERT #tbl_InterCompanyUploadDetail_Staging 
FROM '\\SVRP03546008461D\QA\UploadTemplatewithvalidation.xlsx'
 WITH (FIRSTROW = 6, FIELDTERMINATOR ='\t', ROWTERMINATOR ='\\n' )
```

Error that I am getting is :

> Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 6, column 2 (Oracle Company Code).

The column in Excel has data as 470 and in database column is varchar (10).
So what could be the reason for the error.

Comment: As the error message says, truncation is the reason for the error.  Presumably the column in the data has more than 10 characters.

Comment: No, I have only ten rows in it and every row has 3 character. That is why I am confused.

Comment: I didn't know that `BULK INSERT` could insert `.xlsx` files. Unless this is a new feature.... I don't think that's possible. What does this file look like if you open it in notepad?

Comment: it open in encrypted format

Comment: I saved in txt format it open fine. ok So any idea how can we figure out FIELDTERMINATOR for excel

Comment: The documentation explains it very well: [Import data from Excel to SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-data-from-excel-to-sql?view=sql-server-2017). `BULK INSERT` supports only plain text files, it can't read from Excel file.

Comment: To spell it out: you first need to export your xlsx file as a text file (say CSV) then import the text file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## The Issue

`BULK INSERT` may not work with xlsx files, try converting the `.xlsx` file to `.csv` file to achieve this *(using `BULK INSERT`)*

## 1st Solution - using OPENROWSET

Try using `OPENROWSET` with `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` provider:

```
Insert into <rawdatatable> 
select * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
                         'Excel 12.0;Database=D:\SSIS\FileToLoad.xlsx;HDR=YES', 
                         'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

OR

```
SELECT * INTO Data_dq
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'Excel 12.0; Database=D:\Desktop\Data.xlsx', [Sheet1$]);
```

## 2nd Solution - using OPENDATASOURCE

```
SELECT * INTO Data_dq
FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'Data Source=D:\Desktop\Data.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0')...[Sheet1$];
```

## References

- [Import/Export Excel (.Xlsx) or (.Xls) File into SQL Server](http://www.ashishblog.com/importexport-excel-xlsx-or-xls-file-into-sql-server/)
- [Import data from Excel to SQL Server or Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-data-from-excel-to-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
- [How to Bulk Insert from XLSX file extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13124680/how-to-bulk-insert-from-xlsx-file-extension/13124749)

Answer (score 0):

Replace "\n" with "0x0a" as ROWTERMINATOR and try again.

Or also

```
 ROWTERMINATOR = '''+cast (0x0000 as char(1))+'''
```

Let me know if it works.

Check also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479819/bulk-insert-sql-server-2000-unix-linebreaks).

Comment: '''+cast (0x0000 as char(1))+''' this doesn't work and when using "0x0a" then getting error: "Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row"

Comment: You checked also the link?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt using XLSX file with BULK INSERT. If XLSX file supported, then FIELDTERMINATOR and ROWTERMINATOR are not needed.

XLSX is zip file so I guess (but not sure) XLSX not supported and you are getting truncation error because it is reading it as pure text file and BULK INSERT getting long text up to FIELDTERMINATOR.

To confirm, you try increasing length of column up to some thousand character and run BULK INSERT, if you get garbage character then it is reading it as pure text file. may be garbage character could be same as you open same xlsx file in notepad or notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

You can't bulk load XLSX into SQL Server. You CAN convert the XLSX to a tab delimited text file and bulk load.

If this is a one-off operation I would recommend converting to text first (but beware how Excel exports certain types like dates and large numbers). Or you can use the Import/Export wizard (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-data-from-excel-to-sql)

If this is a process you need to repeat I would create an SSIS script.